# Jquery Max-Width statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, frontend

I'm trying to open up my iframe in a lightbox with a maximum width of 700px but when the screen's smaller then that, it'll be 100%.

this works at setting the width a fixed 700

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"700px", height:"800px"});
```

But everytime i try to do this

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"100%", max-width:"700px", height:"800px"});
```

the iframe lightbox doesn't work... it just opens up like a normal page... any clues guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript objects don't allow special characters in object keys that aren't quoted. `max-width` would qualify, and thus throw an error. Look in your browser console

This error will block code from running

If you look at the plugin docs, the correct option to use is: `maxWidth`